# Trying to Update a Column in SQL Server 2008 using CASE and a Condition based on another Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, case

I am trying to update a table with two columns in it based on the values in other columns.  I have a syntax error and now I slight case of misery.   So I want to update the column `MONETARY` based on the value in column `NET_SALES` and I want to update the column `RECENCY` based on the value in column `DLP`.  Thoughts?

```
UPDATE #CC201403B_CURRENT
 SET MONETARY=CASE 
  WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '75.00' AND '100.00') THEN '75-100'
  WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '100.01' AND '125.00') THEN '100-125'
  WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '125.01' AND '175.00') THEN '125-175'
  WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '175.01' AND '250.00') THEN '175-250'
  ELSE '250+' END,
 SET RECENCY=CASE
  WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '3/1/2013' AND '5/31/2013') THEN 'DLP 10-12'
  WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '6/1/2013' AND '8/31/2013') THEN 'DLP 7-9'
  WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '9/1/2013' AND '11/30/2013') THEN 'DLP 4-6'
  WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '12/1/2013' AND '2/28/2014') THEN 'DLP 0-3' 
  ELSE '' END;
```

Comment: what is your syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

You have the keyword `SET` 2 times in your query, and you do not need it. Try the following query.

```
UPDATE #CC201403B_CURRENT
SET 
    MONETARY = CASE 
        WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '75.00' AND '100.00') THEN '75-100'
        WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '100.01' AND '125.00') THEN '100-125'
        WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '125.01' AND '175.00') THEN '125-175'
        WHEN (NET_SALES BETWEEN '175.01' AND '250.00') THEN '175-250'
        ELSE '250+' END,
    RECENCY = CASE
        WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '3/1/2013' AND '5/31/2013') THEN 'DLP 10-12'
        WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '6/1/2013' AND '8/31/2013') THEN 'DLP 7-9'
        WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '9/1/2013' AND '11/30/2013') THEN 'DLP 4-6'
        WHEN (DLP BETWEEN '12/1/2013' AND '2/28/2014') THEN 'DLP 0-3' 
        ELSE '' END;
```